# octave gnuplot throws a no data error on plot command

Tags: gnuplot, octave

Typing in the command `plot 100` returns the following error
`error: plot: no data to plot error: called from: error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/draw/private/__plt__.m at line 126, column 11 error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/draw/plot.m at line 220, column 10`

I have modified my octave by putting in the following environment variable within octaverc. `setenv("GNUTERM","x11")`. The graph does actually come up when the plot command is called, but there is no data displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is expected, since `plot 100` is not a valid use of [`plot`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html).

You can also try `demo plot` to get examples.

Comment: This. Your test invocation should be `plot (100)`.